# PHP Get array value using foreach

Tags: php

PHP how to get array value:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['cb']);

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tipe] => read
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [tipe] => update
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [tipe] => update
    )

)
?>
```

So what I want to get maybe in `foreach` function like this:

```
foreach(...)
{
   $qInsert = oci_parse("INSERT INTO TDATA(ID, CHKSTATUS) VALUES('$getID', '$getTipe')");
   oci_execute($qInsert);
}
```

`$getID` means the [id], and `$getTipe` means the [tipe] in array.

Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: I would suggest you : not to execute the query N times, depending on the array size. insert all the data in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Array has 100s of indices, your query will execute 100 times to insert data. Avoid such operations as much as possible, See the answer below, you can insert data in a single query, the code is not tested, you can adjust to meet your requirements .

```
$dataArray = $_POST['cb']; 
$queryData = null;

foreach($dataArray as $data){

    $queryData[]="(".$data['id'].", '".$data['tipe']."')";

}

$values = implode(',',$queryData);
$qInsert = oci_parse("INSERT INTO TDATA(ID, CHKSTATUS) VALUES ".$values."");
oci_execute($qInsert);
```

I hope this might save your database operations overhead

Comment: Hi Shan, thanks for the answer. Tried your code, but it only save if I only choose 1 checkbox. If more its not save to db. Please advice.

Comment: try to echo "INSERT INTO TDATA(ID, CHKSTATUS) VALUES ".$values."" & see the complete query

Comment: This is when I echo, INSERT INTO TDATA(ID, CHKSTATUS) VALUES ('1', 'create'),('1', 'update'),('2', 'read'),('2', 'delete')

Comment: btw, I'm using ORACLE

Comment: If the ID field is a primary key this query will only insert one value, Because of duplicate ID value '1'